# Как найти два числа, если известно их НОД и НОК?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, математика, freepascal

Входные данные
В первой строке дано натуральное число
A
— НОД некоторых двух натуральных чисел(
1
⩽
A
⩽
10000
).

Во второй строке дано натуральное число
B
— НОК некоторых двух натуральных чисел(
1
⩽
B
⩽
10000
).

Выходные данные
Выведите два натуральных числа через пробел (неважно в каком порядке), НОД которых равен
A
и НОК которых равен
B
. Если таких чисел не существует, выведите -1.

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с того, что если это числа a и b, то

a*b = НОД*НОК

Кроме того, a = НОД*a1, и b = НОД*b1.

Так что задача - найти такие a1 и b1, у которых НОД=1 (взаимно простые).

a1 = 1 и b1 = НОК/НОД подходят, как одно из решений, так что a = НОД, b = НОК является решением. Прочие можно искать разложением на простые сомножители и перебирать все возможные вариант (а их может оказаться много :)).

Очевидно, что решение существует не для всех с потолка взятых НОД и НОК - как минимум, НОК должно делиться на НОД.

Могут быть и другие решения. Вам нужно найти **все решения** или **любое решение**?

Как я понимаю из условия, хватит и одного. Тогда

```
int GCD, LCM;
cin >> GCD >> LCM;
if (LCM % GCD != 0) cout << -1; 
else cout << GCD << " " << LCM/GCD;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё верно, требуется любое решение

Comment: Ну, осталось выбрать, какое из решений принять :)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку

```
НОК(a, b) = a * b / НОД(a, b)
```

То сразу можно найти произведение чисел, а дальше надо просто решить в лоб:

1. перебрать все числа a, b
2. вычислить НОД(a, b) и проверить на совпадение

Цикл, чтобы работал побыстрее можно сделать так:

```
mul = lcm / gcd

for a in range(1, mul + 1):
    if mul % a != 0:
        continue

    b = mul // a

    if gcd_func(a, b) == gcd:
        print(a, b)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогли